# How to remove html unicode content from the last element of a dynamic list?

Tags: html, css, unicode

```css
li:after{ content:"\00b6"; }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li class="last-class">apple</li>
</ol>
```

I working on a dynamic list (the no of `<li>` tags are varying on time  ).I need to be remove the html  unicode content from the last element.the last element have a class(here it is "last-class").Is it possible to do with css?

**Note** : I know it's possible with different fonts.I did not use that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:not` pseudo-class to add the pseudo-element only to elements other than the last child.

```css
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "\00b6";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li class="last-class">apple</li>
</ol>
```

---

As you've indicated that you only need to remove it from the last element, the class is not really required but you can do it with the class also like in the below snippet:

```css
li:not(.last-class):after {
  content: "\00b6";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li class="last-class">apple</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: tnx that is a new **knowledge** for me

Answer (score 0):

```
li:last-child:after {content: "";}
```

This one your are looking for? Add this also to your css

Comment: sorry. not for this